# How can I run two dev servers with yarn workspaces?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, workspace, lerna, monorepo

I have two yarn workspaces **A** and **B**.

Within each workspace, I can run `yarn start` to run webpack dev server on different ports.

Therefore, I am trying to use the command `yarn workspaces run start` to start dev servers in both workspace **A** and **B**.

However, it only runs `yarn start` in workspace **A** and leaves the session open. My guess is it can't run `yarn start` for workspace **B** until the previous command ends.

Is there another simple way I can go about achieving this? I haven't been able to find any examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think workspaces supports this. But lerna exposes a `--parallel` flag you can pass in that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to install the `concurrently` package and in your `package.json` scripts do something like:

```
...
"start": "concurrently \"yarn start:A\" \"yarn start:B\",
"start:A": "cd A; yarn start",
"start:B": "cd B; yarn start",
...
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently